# Exponential simultaneous equations, short multiplication formulas - only for sneaky people

Tags: systems-of-equations, quadratics

I am obligated to do some exercises from some Russian maths book and I solved them, but the teacher told us to use the smartest possible way to achieve this and I guess mine aren't sneaky enough and my teacher won't be proud of me. So I came up with an idea to cheat a bit and ask u guys for some ideas. I hope you will be eager to help me :)

So these are equations I have a problem with:

[photo of exercises](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHMN8.jpg)

Here is another one that I think is much harder. I can't solve it. I would be very grateful for your time and help.$$12(x+y)^2+x=2.5-y\\
6(x-y)^2+x=0.125+y$$

I don't need whole solutions, I already got them and spent hours solving like 20 of similiar ones. I just need some smart and sneaky ideas from you guys there's a lot of short multiplication formulas knowledge and usage.

Comment: I already got an idea for the last one. 3 more needed :)

Comment: I edited your question to include the new problem, and edited my answer below with a hint to solve it.

Comment: Thank you for your help :) It turned out to be the simplest one, but for some reason I couldn't have come up with the solution. I'm not used to using ancillary variables when solving the equations, but now I can see it's really helpful. Thank you very much once again.

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For #$6087$ :  divide the $1$st by the $2$nd equation we have $x^2+y^2=2.5xy$. Let $y = tx$ then $x = 0$ or $t^2 + 1 = 5t$ .For #$6091$ you can use the same trick.